# Maps API instantiacion and usage limit

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The usage of google maps api is limited with a number of request.
In fact we can't generate up to 25,000 map loads :
https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits

My question is about instanciation (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true...).
Is this instantiacion considere as a maps load and is taken in the request count ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Calling the API is not considered as a maps-load, a map-Load is a successfull creation of a `google.maps.Map`-instance.